# Comparar dois caracteres em diferentes funções em c

Tags: c, string

Estou iniciando o estudo de ponteiros e necessito resolver uma atividade. Recebo 3 valores e preciso ordena-los em crescente ou decrescente, função definida pelo usuário. É nesse momento que estou encontrando dificuldade, para comparar os caracteres uso a função *strcmp()*, mas quando recebo o valor vindo de outra variável a função não identifica nenhuma igualdade.

Estrutura comparadora:

```
int orders(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3, char side[1]){

    
    result = strcmp(&side,"c");

    if(result>=0){
        if(result==0){
            printf("crescent");

        }
        else{
            result = strcmp(&side, "d");
            if(result==0){
                printf("decrescent");

            }else{
                printf("Put something right");
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("put something right");
    }
}
```

Formato em que estou passando o caracter:

```
 printf("Inform the ordering format: (c/d)");
 gets(ordering);
 strlwr(ordering);

orders(ordering);
```

Quando a função orders recebe o valor de "ordering", e faz a comparação, devolve sempre 1, mesmo colocando como valor de entrada "c".

Comment: Funcionamento da função "strcmp()", https://www.delftstack.com/pt/howto/c/compare-char-in-c/

Comment: A função `orders()` foi declarada com o retorno do tipo `int` mas não retorna nenhum valor. Veja a declaração [`return`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return)

Comment: poste um programa completo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu programa não faz sentido

```
int orders(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3, char side[1]){

    
    result = strcmp(&side,"c");

    if(result>=0){
        if(result==0){
            printf("crescent");

        }
        else{
            result = strcmp(&side, "d");
            if(result==0){
                printf("decrescent");

            }else{
                printf("Put something right");
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("put something right");
    }
}
```

Essa função recebe 3 ponteiros para `int` porque imagino que vá colocar na ordem especificada por `side` os valores de `n1`, `n2` e `n3`. E retorna um `int`.

Mas:

- `char side[1]` é um vetor de 1 único `char`. Qual o propósito de um vetor de uma única coisa? Qual a vantagem em relação a declarar `char side` simplesmente?
- se é um vetor de um único `char` só pode ser uma string: a string vazia, porque tem que ter um `0` no fim. Isso quer dizer que `strcmp()` nunca vai retornar `0`, já que `"c"` tem dois bytes e não caberia em `side` que só tem 1.
- se retorna um 'int' porque não tem um `return` no código? O usual seria retornar `0` se classificou ou `-1` se `side` não era `c` ou `d`

Por outro lado:

```
 printf("Inform the ordering format: (c/d)");
 gets(ordering);
 strlwr(ordering);

orders(ordering);
```

- não use `gets`. Nunca. Isso foi abolido há décadas e nem existe em alguns compiladores.
- se `orders()` tem 4 parâmetros o que está passando em `ordering`? Não faz sentido.

#### um exemplo

Imagino que esse seja um exercício para mostrar como tratar ponteiros para retornar vários valores. Entenda que 3 valores podem ter apenas 6 classificações, 3!:

```
   1 2 3
   1 3 2 
   2 1 3
   2 3 1
   3 1 2
   3 2 1
```

E assim

- um grupo de `if` classifica isso. O mais fácil é escrever em um papel e copiar para o programa.
- ordem crescente ou decrescente só inverte o primeiro com o terceiro

**Se você tiver uma função assim**

```
int test_f(const int A, const int B, const int C)
{ 
    int a = A;
    int b = B;
    int c = C;
    printf("\nOriginal values: [%d, %d, %d]\n", a, b, c);
    int res = orders(&a, &b, &c, 'c');
    printf("[A] orders() returned (%d) [%d, %d, %d]\n", res, a, b, c);
    a = A, b = B, c = C;
    res = orders(&a, &b, &c, 'd');
    printf("[D] orders() returned (%d) [%d, %d, %d]\n", res, a, b, c);
    char criteria = 'X';
    res = orders(&a, &b, &c, criteria);
    printf("For '%c' criteria, orders() returned (%d)\n", criteria, res);
    return 0;
}
```

Ela faz todos os testes se chamar

```
    test_f(3, 1, 2);
    test_f(3, 2, 1);
    test_f(1, 2, 3);
    test_f(1, 3, 2);
    test_f(2, 1, 3);
    test_f(2, 3, 1);
```

Para não repetir o código das comparações e inverter os sinais conforme seja crescente ou decrescente em dois lugares pode usar 2 funções

```
int orderA(int*, int*, int*);        // Ascending
int orderD(int*, int*, int*);        // Descending
```

E uma pode usar a outra, como em

```
int orderD(int* n1, int* n2, int* n3)
{
    orderA(n1, n2, n3);
    int temp = *n3;
    *n3  = *n1;
    *n1  = temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Porque são só 3 elementos afinal.

E sua função `orders()` pode ser só

```
int orders(int* n1, int* n2, int* n3, char side)
{
    if ((side == 'c') || (side == 'C')) return orderA(n1,n2,n3);
    if ((side == 'd') || (side == 'D')) return orderD(n1,n2,n3);
    return -1;  // invalido
}
```

que é bem mais fácil de ler.

#### o código completo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int orders(int*, int*, int*, char);  // for the compiler

int orderA(int*, int*, int*);        // Ascending
int orderD(int*, int*, int*);        // Descending
int test_f(const int, const int, const int); // for easier testing

int main(void)
{
    test_f(3, 1, 2);
    test_f(3, 2, 1);
    test_f(1, 2, 3);
    test_f(1, 3, 2);
    test_f(2, 1, 3);
    test_f(2, 3, 1);
    return 0;
};

int orders(int* n1, int* n2, int* n3, char side)
{
    if ((side == 'c') || (side == 'C')) return orderA(n1,n2,n3);
    if ((side == 'd') || (side == 'D')) return orderD(n1,n2,n3);
    return -1;  // invalido
}

int orderA(int* n1, int* n2, int* n3)
{
    // it is a 3-way comparison
    // write in a piece of paper, then transcript :) 
    // 3! = 6 possible results
    int a=0,b=0,c=0;
    if (*n1 < *n2)
    { 
        if (*n1 < *n3)
        {
            // n1 is min
            a = *n1;
            if (*n2 < *n3)
            {
                b = *n2;
                c = *n3;                    // 123
            }
            else
            {
                b = *n3;                    // 132
                c = *n2;
            };
        }
        else
        {
            // n3 is min
            a = *n3;
            if (*n1 < *n2)
            {
                b = *n1;
                c = *n2;                    // 312
            }
            else
            {
                b = *n2;
                c = *n1;                    // 321
            };
        }

    }
    else
    {   //   n1 >= n2
        if (*n3 < *n2)
        {  // n3 is min
            a = *n3;
            if (*n1 < *n2)
            {
                b = *n1;
                c = *n2;                    // 312
            }
            else
            {
                b = *n2;
                c = *n1;                    // 321
            }
        }
        else
        {  // n2 is min
            a = *n2;
            if (*n1 < *n3)
            {
                b = *n1;
                c = *n3;                    // 213
            }
            else
            {
                b = *n3;
                c = *n1;                    // 231
            }
        }
    }; // if 1
    *n1 = a, *n2 = b, *n3 = c;
    return 0;
}

int orderD(int* n1, int* n2, int* n3)
{
    orderA(n1, n2, n3);
    int temp = *n3;
    *n3  = *n1;
    *n1      = temp;
    return 0;
}

int test_f(const int A, const int B, const int C)
{ 
    int a = A;
    int b = B;
    int c = C;
    printf("\nOriginal values: [%d, %d, %d]\n", a, b, c);
    int res = orders(&a, &b, &c, 'c');
    printf("[A] orders() returned (%d) [%d, %d, %d]\n", res, a, b, c);
    a = A, b = B, c = C;
    res = orders(&a, &b, &c, 'd');
    printf("[D] orders() returned (%d) [%d, %d, %d]\n", res, a, b, c);
    char criteria = 'X';
    res = orders(&a, &b, &c, criteria);
    printf("For '%c' criteria, orders() returned (%d)\n", criteria, res);
    return 0;
}
```

que mostra

```
Original values: [3, 2, 1]
[A] orders() returned (0) [1, 2, 3]
[D] orders() returned (0) [3, 2, 1]
For 'X' criteria, orders() returned (-1)

Original values: [1, 2, 3]
[A] orders() returned (0) [1, 2, 3]
[D] orders() returned (0) [3, 2, 1]
For 'X' criteria, orders() returned (-1)

Original values: [1, 3, 2]
[A] orders() returned (0) [1, 2, 3]
[D] orders() returned (0) [3, 2, 1]
For 'X' criteria, orders() returned (-1)

Original values: [2, 1, 3]
[A] orders() returned (0) [1, 2, 3]
[D] orders() returned (0) [3, 2, 1]
For 'X' criteria, orders() returned (-1)

Original values: [2, 3, 1]
[A] orders() returned (0) [1, 2, 3]
[D] orders() returned (0) [3, 2, 1]
For 'X' criteria, orders() returned (-1)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, e pelos concelhos! Mas o que eu poderia usar ao invés de gets()?

Comment: use fgets(). É o candidato natural

Comment: vou colocar um exemplo ao final da resposta

Comment: uma dúvida, quando eu faço a expressão `if((side == 'c'))` não tem o funcionamento esperado. Certeza que seria esse o uso correto?

Comment: isso que eu te mostrei é a execução do programa. Deveria ser igualzinho em sua máquina.

Comment: sim, mas se você utiliza esse formato de comparação, para entrada de usuário, não funciona, sabe me dizer o porque?

Comment: Faça outra pergunta com o código, ou edite esta e coloque o novo código, e assim posso te dizer porque

Comment: Fiquei fazendo alguns testes aqui e percebi que meu erro estava em um conceito básico de C. Na minha entrada de usuário quero receber apenas um caracter e eu estrava tratando o valor como string. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!